# Ubuntu won't boot after installing a new kernel

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, vmware

I am a software tester, and I'm trying to test a kernel module on a variety of Linux kernels (3.2+). Currently I'm trying to compile the module, mount it and run an automated test suite on all Linux kernels 3.2 onwards.

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 on a virtual machine, with `kernel 3.13.0-32-generic`. My plan was to download the git repository from `https://github.com/torvalds/linux`, checkout `n` version (i.e. 3.14.0), compile it with default configuration (I don't really care to tune the kernel), install it, boot with the new kernel, compile my kernel module, mount it, test it, clean up, rinse and repeat.

So in order to learn this ordeal, I tried to install 3.14.0.

I run the usual command (I think):

```
make defconfig && make && make modules && make install && make modules_install
```

Yey! I think I installed it, `grub.cfg` already shows the default boot option to use the new kernel. I can see `vmlinusz-3.14.0` and `initrd.img-3.14.0` under `/boot`.

However, when I reboot the VM, I get this:

```
ALERT! /dev/disk/by-uuid/231ea9ac-f01d-42dc-830b-f3ecd4775148 does not exist. Dropping to a shell.
```

I see that that the HDD is not even listed at `/dev` (there is no `sda`).

When I run `cat /proc/cmdline` I get:

```
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.14.0 root=UUID=231ea9ac-f01d-42dc-830b-f3ecd4775148 ro quiet splash
```

When I go back to `3.13.0-32-generic`, I can see the devices, I can find `/dev/disk/by-uuid/231ea9ac-f01d-42dc-830b-f3ecd4775148` file. Also, `fstab` shows:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=231ea9ac-f01d-42dc-830b-f3ecd4775148 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=db20004e-9c66-436c-b572-aa44deb571fa none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/fd0        /media/floppy0  auto    rw,user,noauto,exec,utf8 0       0
```

I don't really know where to look at anymore.

I'm working with a VM, however I can't edit, create, remove VMs in VMware, just in case (I don't manage the environment).

Why isn't it booting under 3.14.0? Did I do something wrong?